# Restful management of Devise model records | Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a project that involves two Devise models (`User` and `Admin`). What I'd like to do is allow for `Admin` members to be able to view and manage `User`s in a RESTful way (i.e: index, show, create, update, destroy).

Would the best way be to create a `users_controller` and treat it like an average RESTful model (modifying each controller action to work with Devise where applicable)?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

**CLARIFICATION UPDATE**
It seems I wasn't clear about the question above. Answers below are about the authorisation of actions affecting the `User` model. This isn't what I'm asking about. I'm asking about the best way to facilitate the transaction itself, not the authorisation and restriction of the transaction. What would be the best way to have `Admin` members creating `User`s and updating `User` records without using the standard Devise self-signup. My intention is to disable self-signup so as to only allow new `User` registration by an `Admin` member creating the `User` account. Hopefully, this is more clear. Thanks.

Comment: This is really an authorization issue...where you only allow records to be managed by admins and record owners (where applicable). Have you implemented any kind of authorization system (whether it's a gem like [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) or your own)?

Comment: @MarkMerritt: thanks for your response. What I’m asking about is how to facilitate the actual RESTful management of the `User` records by `Admin` members, regardless of the authorisation for now, but the authorisation side of things will be next! Thanks again.

Comment: The most RESTful way, regardless of the type of record you are trying to manage, is to have a separate `/admin` base route, that only admin users are able to access.

Comment: @MarkMerritt: Thanks for your input, I've updated my question for some extra clarification about what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you take a look at the following gems Rolify and CanCan, there were integrated with devise here.

Here's [a link](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated the question with some clarification about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you need only admins to have access to add users, then devise_invitable gem is my advice here,it will allow admins send email invitations to users,that way users will be created only when admin sends an invite.